# putting image always in center page

Tags: css

putting image always in center page(E.x image loading for ajax call), even when move scroll. how is it?

Comment: You need to use `position: fixed` to keep it in the center even when scrolling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For most browsers, you can use `position:fixed`

```
 img.centered {
     position:fixed;
     left: 50%;
     top:  50%;
     /*
         if, for instance, the image is 64x64 pixels,
         then "move" it half its width/height to the
         top/left by using negative margins
     */
     margin-left: -32px;
     margin-top:  -32px;
 }
```

If the image was, for instance, 40x30 pixels, you'd set `margin-left:-20px; margin-top:-15px` instead.

Here's a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/WnSnj/1/

Please note that position:fixed doesn't work exactly the same in all browsers (though it's ok in all the modern ones). See: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html

Answer (score 3):

```
<style>
.CenterScreen{
   position:fixed;
   /*element can move on the screen (only screen, not page)*/

   left:50%;top:50%;
   /*set the top left corner of the element on the center of the screen*/

   transform:translate(-50%,-50%);}
   /*reposition element center with screen center*/

  z-index:10000;
  /*actually, this number is the count of the elements of page  plus 1 :)*/
  /*if you need that holds the element top of the others. */
</style>
```

If you add this class your element, it will be always center of the screen.

For example:

```
<a href="#" class="CenterScreen">Hello world</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you : http://skfox.com/2008/04/28/jquery-example-ajax-activity-indicator/

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in a div tag with some class name (centeredImage) and use the following css

```
div.centeredImage {

  margin: 0px auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;//whatever you want to set top;

}
```