# Keep an Image Always Centered Regardless of Browser Size

Tags: html, css

I am wondering if it is possible to keep an `img` inside a `div` always centered regardless of the browser size? By being centered I mean that the left/right sides of the image gets cropped to ensure the image stays centered without modifying the height. Also, is it possible to prevent the horizontal scroll bar from appearing when the browser width is less then the image width?

I'm sure this is really easy to do if my image is located in a `background-url` tag in CSS, but because this image is being housed inside the SlidesJS carousel the image has to be from an `img` tag.

At the moment, I have used `margin:0 auto;` to keep the image centered as long as the browser width is larger then the image. Once the browser width shrinks, the image does not resize with the shrinking browser size. I also have yet to figure out how to remove the horizontal scroll bar when the browser width is too small.

This is what I'm trying to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/amw3O.jpg

This is an example of what the page layout is suppose to look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J8O7.jpg

Example of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/9tRZG/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="slides">
        <div class="slides_container">
            <div class="slide"> <!-- Carousel slide #1 -->
                <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x50/">
            </div>
            <div class="slide"> <!-- Carousel slide #1 -->
                <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x50/">
            </div>
            <div class="slide"> <!-- Carousel slide #1 -->
                <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x50/">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}​
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890552/putting-image-always-in-center-page

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/9tRZG/1/

```
#wrapper {
    max-width: 200px; /* max-width doesn't behave correctly in legacy IE */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#wrapper img{
    width:100%;       /* the image will now scale down as its parent gets smaller */
}
​
```

To have the edges cropped, you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/9tRZG/2/

```
#wrapper {
    max-width: 600px; /* so this will scale down when the screen resizes */
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;  /* so that the children are cropped */
    border:solid 1px #000; /* you can remove this, I'm only using it to demonstrate the bounding box */
}

#wrapper .slides_container{
    width:600px;            /* static width here */
    position:relative;      /* so we can position it relative to its parent */
    left:50%;               /* centering the box */
    margin-left:-300px;     /* centering the box */
}
#wrapper img{
    display:block;          /* this allows us to use the centering margin trick */
    margin: 2px auto;       /* the top/bottom margin isn't necessary here, but the left/right is */
}
```

Comment: That looks great, but I don't want the height of the image to be modified. I just want the edges to be cropped out as needed to keep the image centered.

Comment: For the fun of it, I worked out your desired layout: http://jsfiddle.net/9tRZG/3/

Comment: I feel it's appropriate to mention that the jsfiddle above with cycling images doesn't keep all the images centred if they have differing image widths.

Answer (score 3):

Jeff Hines linked [putting image always in center page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890552/putting-image-always-in-center-page) where ShankarSangoli explained how to achieve this.

```
img.centered {
     position:fixed;
     left: 50%;
     top:  50%;
     /*
         if, for instance, the image is 64x64 pixels,
         then "move" it half its width/height to the
         top/left by using negative margins
     */
     margin-left: -32px;
     margin-top:  -32px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the align center looks proper to me as for the **scroll bar**.
You can use the following:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work. Where did you apply `overflow-x:hidden;` to?

Comment: you can apply it to body or the div that is contains the scrollbar.

Comment: This could be a browser issue try the following:   body {
overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
___

Comment: Applying `overflow-x` to the body seemed to have done the trick, but I only need it applied to the image. When I did that, it still did not work. Regardless @Jeff Hines has linked a solution. Thank you for your help though :)