# enable bxSlider outside of container bounds

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

Ok, this might tough to explain. I have responsive HTML5 document I'm working on. The container has a max-width of 1000px, but I would like to have a slider (bxSlider) inside the container, but needs to go beyond the container bounds. The width needs to be 1322px. I've tried some absolute positioning, but the slider is not reacting quite right. I also need it to be centered so equal portions are outside of the 1000px container.

Basically, I want the same behavior as a background image in a div with background-position: top center, but applying to a div containing the bxSlider.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay.. I got it figured out with this stackoverflow post:
[Keep an Image Always Centered Regardless of Browser Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396794/keep-an-image-always-centered-regardless-of-browser-size)

Shmiddty's answer worked perfectly!