# I cant properly center this and ive tried every search result ive found

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to code the box to be centered on the page, I've tried almost everything I can find on the web. Here is my CSS:

```
.boxbg {
position: center;
width:100%;
height:100%; 
top:1em;
left:1em;
bottom:1em;
right:1em;
margin: auto;
align-content: center;
}
.bgcolor {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top: 0em;
left:0em;
bottom:0em;
right:0em;
background-color:#000000;
opacity:0.5;
}

.boxbg1 {
position: absolute;
width: 50%;
}
.box {
width:26.50em;
height:30em; /*Height of whole thing*/
background:#ffffff;
border:0.063em solid grey;
padding:1.250em;
border-radius:10.625em; /*-webkit-*/
border-radius:0.625em;
box-shadow:#333 0.313em 0.313em 0.125em;/*-webkit-*/
margin-left: 50%;
margin-right: 50%;
margin-top: auto;
text-align: left;
}    `
```

I am using Visual Studio Code and uploading the file to Chrome.

Comment: where is your html code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [putting image always in center page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890552/putting-image-always-in-center-page)

Comment: Have you tried to use flexbox to center your elements?
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-13

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align horizontally center then add `margin:0 auto;` and remove other margin to .box
If you want to align Vertically center then add `margin-top:50%` and `transform:translatey(-50%)` to .box. 
Hope this helps. thanks